# AngularJS: ¿Cómo implementar un botón que actualice el template de una ruta?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Por ejemplo este código JavaScript actualiza la página completamente: `<a id="reload" href="javascript:location.reload()"></a>`. Pero lo que quiero hacer es que sólo se actualice el template en el que esté en ese momento y no toda la página. Estoy utilizando ngRoute para las rutas y los templates.

Así es como estoy implementado la solución, pero, no me funciona:

```js
app.component('reloadComponent', {
  template: '<a id="reload" ng-click="refresh()"></a>',
  controller: ['$scope', function reloadComponentCtrl($scope){
    $scope.refresh = function(){
      $route.reload();
    };
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `$route.reload();` consigues lo mismo. Y si estas utilizando `$state` solo inyecta en tu controlador `$state` y ejecuta `$state.reload();`

```
<a ng-click="refresh()">Click</a>
```

Y

```
$scope.refresh = function(){
    $route.reload();
}
```

> `reload();` El servicio `$route` y la llamada `reload()` recargan la ruta actual, incluso si `$location` actual no ha cambiado y "re-instancia" el controlador.

[AngularJS $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta como he implementado tu respuesta a ver si puedes ayudarme, porque no me funciona.

Comment: Debes agregar $route en las dependiencias, igual que $scope

Comment: Cómo no me he dado cuenta lol. Pero ahora tengo otro problema, al actualizar con ese botón, por alguna razón, deja de funcionar el controlador de Disqus. qué crees que suceda? utilizo esta [directiva de Disqus](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus)

Comment: como deja de funcionar? recibes algun error en consola?

Comment: No, sólo no se muestra.

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer que se aplique un estilo al botón mientras se ejecuta la función?

Comment: Puedes darle una clase

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo con el código que utilice en la pregunta?

Comment: `<a class="tuclase" ng-click="refresh()">Click</a>`

Comment: Me refiero **mientras la función se ejecuta** que cambie de estilo, por ejemplo: por defecto el `<a>` tiene una clase llamada "clase1" y sólo mientras la función del `$route.reload();` se está ejecutando que cambie al estilo "clase2"